# Making broken references extra-visible

Tags: links

I would like to have all the broken links in a document come out purple when I compile, and the working links come out whatever color I've set internal links to.

For example, in the following document's output

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{catfish}
\end{theorem}
Theorem \ref{catfish} implies the truth of Conjecture \ref{god}.
\end{document}
```

I would like the working reference to not be purple, and the broken one, rendered as **??**, to be purple. Is there a reasonable way to do it? (I am sorry if the question was inherently bad or if it was unclear before.)

P.S.: It might also be useful to compile a list of broken links. How might I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Please make *our* life a little easier to provide *you* a solution by providing us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: Please see the revised version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tracingpatches
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@setref}{\bfseries ??}{\bfseries\color{red} undefined Label}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{catfish}
\end{theorem}
Theorem \ref{catfish} implies the truth of Conjecture \ref{god}.
\end{document}
```

[image: undefinedLabel]

Comment: P.S.: Is there a way to modify this so that it also does this for broken citations, e.g., `\cite[p.~666]{ThingNotInMyBibFile}`?

Comment: @jdc Depends on how you are citing. `biblatex` (recommended) behaves different from all the older methods. Please open a new question for that (you can crosslink to keep them somehow related).