# Making broken references extra visible, redux: interacting with BibTeX (or BibLaTeX)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, hyperref, cleveref

In [Making broken references extra-visible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223381/making-broken-references-extra-visible), I asked how to make LaTex's normal **??** and [**?**] markers for broken references instead render as some super-annoying, colored text, so that in skimming a long `book`-class document, I can know instantly what needs fixing.

I have been instructed now how to do this for broken `\ref`s, but the MWE I provided was *too* minimal: I'd also like to know how to similarly mark broken `\cite`s.

Here is an MWE in case there is any doubt what I mean by this.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
 \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{theorem}\label{catfish}
 \end{theorem}
 Theorem \ref{catfish} implies the truth of Theorem \ref{god}, 
 as explained in \cite{what}.
 \bibliography{bibshort}{}
 \end{document}.
```

I was encouraged to use BibLaTeX, but in creating this MWE found that don't seem to be able to use BibLaTeX on my computer, so for the moment I am asking about BibTex. (I would have asked the other question first, but because I started this one first, it seems the site's software requires me to either post it or delete it before I can ask a different question.)

Comment: This will be a lot easier with BibLaTeX - in part because the missing stuff is more visible by default (bold bibkeys are easier to spot than a couple of question marks, typically). You do know that LaTeX gives you this information on the console and in the log, right? So you can easily get a list of all the unresolved things with their locations in the document?

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to figure out BibLaTeX, but my computer and I guess my computer literacy are against me. I know about the *existence* of the log, and often watch it slowly generate while my files compile, but I'm not great at searching through and interpreting the output. Most of it, I just don't understand.

Comment: `grep -i undefined <filename>.log` will give you a list of lines like `LaTeX Warning: Citation 'bibkey' on page 134 undefined on input line 234.` With similar things for unresolved cross references etc. With a little `sed`, `sort` and `uniq` you can parse this further if you wish to e.g. give you a simple list of all undefined bibkeys, or a list of all unresolved references to figures. Or whatever. That is, you have ***your computer*** filter the bits you are interested in so that ***you*** don't have to. For long documents, obviously - not for a couple of pages.

Comment: But you don't need any of that just to use biblatex and biber ;).

Comment: That's really helpful, actually. But I'm really committed to getting the original thing to work now, though, because I've sunk time into it now. I don't know *what* I need to use biblatex and biber, apparently. =|

Comment: I somewhat feel that achieving this with `cleveref` and `biblatex` are two completely unrelated (safe for the goal, of course); so you might benefit from splitting this question in two.

Comment: I agree about the split. However, although tagged biblatex, the question is actually about bibtex. But that is again different from cleveref.

Comment: All right, I'm doing it. I feel like I've asked way too many questions about this now, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Due entirely to the heroics of other people, I've finally gotten `biblatex` and `biber` to work, so feel free to tell me what I should do with `biblatex`. My idea was to use `\@setcite` in analogy with the other answers, but that doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: @moewe: do you have advice on how to achieve these highly visible reference errors with BibLaTeX? I worry that because this question isn't new anymore, it won't get answered, because it took me so long to get BibLaTeX working.

Comment: @cfr: "[with BibLaTeX,] the missing stuff is more visible by default (bold bibkeys are easier to spot than a couple of question marks, typically)" - I vehemently disagree, at least when applying a wider definition of "visible". I just came to this question while searching for a way to make BibLaTeX behave the same as BibTeX by inserting question marks instead of the bolded bibkeys for broken citation references. Using full text search in a large document to find question marks is a great way to find broken citations, but how do I possibly search for arbitrary bolded text?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't think there is any need for vehement disagreement. I agree that if you want to search the output for strings, clearly `??` are easier to find. I wouldn't call this `visibility` but, hey, maybe your eyes work differently from mine. (Actually, this is overwhelmingly likely since my eyes do not work in the normal human fashion.) But if I'm searching rather than visually scanning, I wouldn't search for `??` or bibkeys. I wouldn't search the output at all. Plain text is so much easier to search and parse, I don't see the point in searching the DVI/PDF/PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

With newer `biblatex` versions we can simply redefine the macro `\abx@missing@entry` to change what is shown when a citation is not found.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\abx@missing@entry#1{%
  {\bfseries\color{red} undefined Label: #1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{cicero}

\cite{lorem}
\end{document}
```

---

### Old answer

With `biblatex`, we have to modify `\blx@citation@entry`, a command called for each citation item:

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@citation@entry#1#2{%
  \blx@bibreq{#1}%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\blx@cites}
    {}
    {\listgadd{\blx@cites}{#1}%
     \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@cite{#1}}}%
  \ifinlistcs{#1}{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}
    {}
    {\listcsgadd{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}{#1}}%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@miss@\the\c@refsection}
       {\ifinlistcs{#1}{blx@miss@\the\c@refsection}
          {{\bfseries\color{red} undefined Label:} }
          {\blx@logreq@active{#2{#1}}}}
       {\blx@logreq@active{#2{#1}}}}}
\makeatother
```

To get rid of a spurious space, we can also redefine (this has to be placed within a `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` group)

```
\def\blx@citeadd#1{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@keyalias@\the\c@refsection @#1}
    {\edef\blx@realkey{\csuse{blx@keyalias@\the\c@refsection @#1}}}
    {\def\blx@realkey{#1}}%
  \expandafter\blx@citation\expandafter{\blx@realkey}\blx@msg@cundefon
  \expandafter\blx@ifdata\expandafter{\blx@realkey}
    {\advance\blx@tempcnta\@ne
     \listeadd\blx@tempa{\blx@realkey}}
    {\ifnum\blx@tempcntb>\z@\multicitedelim\fi
     \expandafter\abx@missing\expandafter{\blx@realkey}%
     \advance\blx@tempcntb\@ne}}
```

Where we added a `%` at the end of the second-to-last line.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@citation@entry#1#2{%
  \blx@bibreq{#1}%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\blx@cites}
    {}
    {\listgadd{\blx@cites}{#1}%
     \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@cite{#1}}}%
  \ifinlistcs{#1}{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}
    {}
    {\listcsgadd{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}{#1}}%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@miss@\the\c@refsection}
       {\ifinlistcs{#1}{blx@miss@\the\c@refsection}
          {{\bfseries\color{red} undefined Label:} }
          {\blx@logreq@active{#2{#1}}}}
       {\blx@logreq@active{#2{#1}}}}}

\def\blx@citeadd#1{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@keyalias@\the\c@refsection @#1}
    {\edef\blx@realkey{\csuse{blx@keyalias@\the\c@refsection @#1}}}
    {\def\blx@realkey{#1}}%
  \expandafter\blx@citation\expandafter{\blx@realkey}\blx@msg@cundefon
  \expandafter\blx@ifdata\expandafter{\blx@realkey}
    {\advance\blx@tempcnta\@ne
     \listeadd\blx@tempa{\blx@realkey}}
    {\ifnum\blx@tempcntb>\z@\multicitedelim\fi
     \expandafter\abx@missing\expandafter{\blx@realkey}%
     \advance\blx@tempcntb\@ne}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{cicero}

\cite{lorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is "lorem" in your `bib` document then? I've just inserted the code in with the other replacement commands, and so far it looks the same as before. My preamble contains all the packages in yours, so I wonder if something's clashing with it.

Comment: @jdc Of, course not, that was the point `;-)`. You can try the MWE on your machine (`biblatex-example.bib` is a file that comes with every `biblatex` installation) and tell me whether or not it works. If it does work as expected, the clash is probably caused by some other package you load (though that would be really weird).

Comment: Right, I meant "Cicero"; he is. Sorry. It works! I just needed to run `biber` again, and forgot for some stupid reason. Thanks! One difference: my undefined label is encased with a bracket, when I run it in my real document, with one extra space after the undefined thing; e.g., "[undefined Label: lorem ]". Any idea how I could rid myself of this space?

Comment: @jdc The square brackets are probably only there in numerical citations. I think getting rid of the space is quite involved and not really worth the hassle. After all, this kind of typographical glitch makes you notice and want to fix the missing reference even more `:-)`.

Comment: @jdc Scrap my earlier comment, it was not that hard to get rid of the space after all. This is probably a bug in `biblatex`. See the edit for a work-around.

Comment: Thanks! What should I read to understand what you've done here?

Comment: @jdc These are all internal macros and commands (mostly from `biblatex2.sty`), so they are sparsely (if at all) documented. Mostly I try to understand the internal structure of the code by examining it and playing around with the code. Note that a work-around for the space problem has been incorporated into `biblatex` ([bug report #296](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/296)) and will (probably) be available with the next release. (At which point it would be advisable to get rid of my work-around - the `\def\blx@citeadd#1{%` part - to avoid complications.)