# Change text of broken autoref references

Tags: hyperref

I would like to replace the `??` displayed when `autoref` cannot find a reference with a custom text, for example `full paper` (that way when the theorem is not present it just points to the full paper) or `\color{red} undefined Label` to make it extra visible.

Somebody gave an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225072/making-broken-cleveref-references-extra-visible/225074?noredirect=1#comment1282106_225074) for `cleveref`, but I'd a solution involving only `autoref`.

Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{catfish}
\end{theorem}
\autoref{catfish} implies the truth of \autoref{god}.
\bibliography{bibshort}{}
\end{document}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xcolor}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\HyRef@autosetref{\bfseries ??}{\missingreftext}{}{\fail}
\newcommand\missingreftext{\textcolor{red}{missing ref}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{catfish}
\end{theorem}
\autoref{catfish} implies the truth of  \autoref{god}.
\end{document}
```

[image]